# Force thunderbird to open the attachment with associated app

Tags: kde, thunderbird

Is there any way to force Thunderbird into opening the attachments with the associated application?

Or at least to open the association dialogue instead of the file open dialogue?

It's really driving me nuts. The easiest way to open the attachments is to save them to disk and open them from the file manager.

Comment: [superuser.com: "How do I make Thunderbird open attachments in the appropriate application?"](http://superuser.com/questions/83030/how-do-i-make-mozilla-thunderbird-opening-attachments-in-appropriate-application), probably helps.

Comment: @sr_ Nope. No useful information there. The extensions are completely useless. I want to open the attachments with the associated apps not to manually create a duplicate of associations.

Comment: Sorry, I was a little fast with this link. I suspect it should be possible to tell Thunderbird to use `kde-open` or `xdg-open`, but I can't find anything about it...

Comment: @sr_ Well yes, that would be a great solution :) But it doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: [This](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=296443) probably is [bad](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=492276) [news](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=694870), although these bug reports refer to Firefox but there might be little hope to have Thunderbird fixed if Firefox isn't, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Security holes to the rescue!

Apparently, both Thunderbird and Firefox (can be configured to) use `/etc/mailcap` which can in turn be used to call `xdg-open`, [see this bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=479010) (referring to [this one](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=19377) including a (rogue) `mailcap` example), [especially comment #2](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=479010#c2) on how to make it (more) secure.